# Undefined index: file in... Can't upload my files

Tags: php, html, file-upload

**This is my php eror log:**

```
[Thu Dec 18 02:40:20.918991 2014] [:error] [pid 6164] [client 127.0.0.1:55890] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /var/www/html/pages/addimage.php on line 3, referer: http://localhost/pages/home.php
[Thu Dec 18 02:40:20.919054 2014] [:error] [pid 6164] [client 127.0.0.1:55890] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /var/www/html/pages/addimage.php on line 3, referer: http://localhost/pages/home.php
[Thu Dec 18 02:40:20.919344 2014] [:error] [pid 6164] [client 127.0.0.1:55890] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /var/www/html/pages/addimage.php on line 5, referer: http://localhost/pages/home.php
[Thu Dec 18 02:40:25.686317 2014] [:error] [pid 6163] [client 127.0.0.1:55901] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /var/www/html/pages/addimage.php on line 3, referer: http://localhost/pages/home.php
[Thu Dec 18 02:40:25.686355 2014] [:error] [pid 6163] [client 127.0.0.1:55901] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /var/www/html/pages/addimage.php on line 3, referer: http://localhost/pages/home.php
[Thu Dec 18 02:40:25.686518 2014] [:error] [pid 6163] [client 127.0.0.1:55901] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /var/www/html/pages/addimage.php on line 5, referer: http://localhost/pages/home.php$
```

**My code:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../img/profile_picture/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "verdun1914", "HateBook");
        $q=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE websiteusers SET image_url='". "../img/profile_picture/". $_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['sess_username']."'");
    }
?>


<div class="addimage-screen">
    <div id="banner_wrap">
        <div class="banner-content">
            <div class="addimage-form" id="Sign-Up">  
                <p><h3>ADD IMAGE<h3></p> 
                <form id="register-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""> 
                    <input type="file"  name="file"><br>
                    <input id="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It actually worked fine and even uploaded files to my server, when this .php file was opening in the new window. Now i just included this file and it doesn't upload files to server.

**BUT!** In my data base it still saves this link: `../img/profile_picture/`.

Thank you·

Comment: Just an FYI, your code is vulnerable to sql injection. And even worse, your code is vulnerable to code injection. I could upload a php script and say it is an image and your code would accept the upload, move it over to within the document root and whenever someone saw my profile image it would actually run the script and do whatever I put in there including send emails, delete files, run commands...etc same as if you had uploaded the script.

Comment: As to fix the question, you should check if `$_FILES['file']` exists prior to using the variables. Do a print_r of `$_FILES` to see what the structure is and what you are getting.

Comment: Mby a link how to prevent this situation? :D

Comment: I checked if it exists- yes. But althrough, it works only when I open the form in new window. If I include the file, it is writing in data base that image_url="../img/profile_picture/".